# Is there a way to support dynamic module loading for non play store app?

Tags: android, resourcebundle, google-play-core

we have an android application which is not on play store ,users install it by downloading from our website . We want to implement dynamic feature loading in our app because not all modules  of the application are useful or in some cases we want to update a specific module since it has few bugs and rest of the application is working fine. Ive read about it and came across play core library but I can't seem to find any article for to achieve it for non play store apps , is there any possibility of doing it ?

Comment: Have you found any possible way for this?

Answer (score 1):

this [article](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/local-development-and-testing-with-fakesplitinstallmanager-57083e1840a4) is awesome

All of the above is not needed anymore if you just want to quickly play with the sample and see how it works locally.

This is thanks to a new --local-testing flag added in bundletool version 0.13.0.
When applied to the bundletool build-apks command, the flag instructs bundletool to add a small piece of meta-data to the generated APK’s manifest. You can then use this in two simple steps:

- Install your app on a test device (or emulator) with bundletool
  install-apks. This triggers an additional push of all split APKs to a
  location on the device’s storage.
- Run the app and create a SplitInstallManager using the usual factory
  method SplitInstallManagerFactory.create(Context).

Comment: I don't think this is what I'm looking for, this is for testing enviornment .

Comment: I test this yesterday, just in emulator can test on demand features ,

Comment: this is magic comand 
`java -jar bundletool.jar install-apks --apks app.apks`

Comment: So if a user downloads the app from my website and he looks to load a new module ,where is the module served from ?

Comment: no no , apk files stored in sd card and when app need them download ,like google play store mecanism

Comment: Oh okay , so that means if I want to update a specific module then I'll have to download the whole app again?

Comment: yes  , and you can test uninstall  that again, that tools is really useful